# Url rewriting broke link to css

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using the following setting for url rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In `index.php` is parse `$_GET['url']` so that in the following examples:

```
ROOT/user/id/1/name/bobby // user is the page, id = 1, name = bobby
ROOT/blog/post/123/title/welcome // blog is the page, post = 123, title = welcome
```

So that the first parameter(? i don't know how to call it) is the page name then the following couple of parameters are like "keys/value".
Now when i browse `ROOT/` the link to stylesheets that are inserted inside the html of the page and the page are shown correctly.
I fi browse `ROOT/index` (which is the same as `ROOT/`) it shows the page (with contents and other stuff) correctly but the links (even if in the html structure are correctly written) to stylesheets are not loaded. And i can see that from the fact that my page has no css at all when i load it.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

The css file's path is as follows:

```
project/view/css/common.css
```

The file where is it included is in

```
project/public/index.php // the one with .htaccess and rewrite rules
```

This brings me to make a link (inside the index.php) such as

```
../view/css/common.css
```

But this works different depending on how the url seems. For examples:

```
# For URL = public/
project/view/css/common.css // good
# For URL = public/index/
project/public/view/css/common.css // broken
# For URL = public/index/key/value
project/public/index/key/view/css/common.css // broken
```

Comment: what does your css links in your html look like? do they have a preceding slash or not?

Comment: @davogotland, my link looks like real paths link.

Comment: @davogotland, they look like this http://localhost/project/public/view/css/index.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two problems (as the given answers didn´t solve your problem yet...):

1. You are rewriting all file-names so when the browser is requesting `css/index.css` your rewrite transforms that to `index.php?url=css/index.css`. @cOle2's answer should solve that.
2. You are not using absolute paths for your css files. The server is translating the requested page like `/user/id/1/name/bobby` to `/index.php?etc....` but when the browser requests for example the css file that is something like `css/index.css` in your code, it will actually request `/user/id/1/name/bobby/css/index.css` and that file does not exist. You can solve that by using only absolute paths to your external files (css, js, images, etc.) like `/css/index.css`.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, both your paths are relative and your css is not accessible by the browser, so you need to:

1. Move the css to the `project/public` directory (like `project/public/css`)
2. Use absolute paths to your css like `/css/index.css`.
3. Make sure the urls to your external files are not rewritten by the server.

Comment: I think it is a good way. The problem is that i'm using relative path such as "../view/css/common.css" to access files in folders which are back to the public folder. How could I turn it into absolute path?

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli What is the root of your web-server compared to your directory structure? If it is `project/public/` then your css files are not publicly accessible so you will need to move them to the `project/public/` directory.

Comment: The directory the user browse is `project/public/` so that he cannot have access to every other folder such as `project/class/` or `project/library/` or `project/view`. While the css file is on `project/view/css/common.css`.

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli That´s the problem then, the user does not have access to the css files in the `project/view` directory.

Answer (score 7):

Comment doesn't let me format the code, can you please try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

## Update

You can try something like this in the `<head>` section of your pages to support relative path for your image/css/js files referenced on that page:

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.example.com/static-files/" />
</head>
```

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: Please try adding base tag to support relative URLs for your static files on the page: eg `<head>
<base href="http://www.example.com/static-files/" />
</head>`

Comment: +1 this was the line that I was looking for to stop my requests to external stuff being rewritten!

Answer (score 2):

You can try removing certain file extensions from the rewrite rule, for example the following rule will disregard images, css and js files.

```
# Do not process images or CSS files further
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
```

Edit: This is how I would apply it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Put it after the RewriteEngine On line

Comment: @cOle2, not working. Also I've updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Take a look @jeroen's answer as it sounds like your paths are relative.

Comment: The simple solution is to put a slash at the start of the path to the css file: /project/view/css/common.css

Also @anubhava update should work too.