# php mvc and .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-routing

I am a new programmer, currently learning php mvc. I am building a framework/mvc system from scratch...Now I am facing problem with .htaccess.

```
    example.com = localhost // unable to post question for localhost link
```

My application url is like this...

```
        http://example.com/mvc/index.php?go=test //test is a controller's name
```

By the help from .htaccess I cleaned the url to....

```
        http://example.com/mvc/test
```

If a controller does not exists it shows an error view, which contains some error message.

```
        http://example.com/mvc/doesnotexists
```

But if I put "/" (forward slash) in the url...

```
        http://example.com/mvc/test/
```

it shows the error but does not load any css or js file.

I have also included controllers method in url...

```
        http://example.com/mvc/test/viewresult
```

If no matched method found in that controller show error message, it shows but same problem...no css nor js.

I have fully loaded css and js if I go through full url

```
        http://example.com/mvc/index.php?go=doesnotexists/
```

and so on

I have tried several .htaccess rules but unable to get it work. Please help and thanks in advance.. My currrent .htaccess code...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  

    # Turn on 
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/
    #RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|media|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|.*\.css|.*\js)

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?go=$1 [QSA,L]

   # Generic 404 for anyplace on the site  
   # ...  

</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's not an URL rewriting problem, albeit you could work aorund the situation with more elaborate rules. You need to fix the resource links in your HTML. Most coders prefer absolute script and style sheet links, but you might as well use the `<base href=>` workaround, which exists for that very purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing CSS file and images after URL rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216306/missing-css-file-and-images-after-url-rewrite)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Url rewriting broke link to css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462897/url-rewriting-broke-link-to-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best solution for css and js is use full path:

```
http://example.com/mvc/assets/style.css

http://cdn.example.com/style.css
```

and rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?go=$1
```

if your 'test' is your controller, and 'param' is action of 'test' controller
you can use

```
http://example.com/mvc/test/param
```

The $_GET['go'] will be 'test/param'
you need explode it to get 'param' action

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS files in the html are **absolute** paths `/assets/mystyle.css` instead of **relative** `assets/mystyle.css` or `../assets/mystyle.css`

Comment: What about using the `<base>` tag?